# Using nth-child of CSS with ngFor in angular2

Tags: css, angular, css-selectors

I have a dynamically generated table using ngFor in angular2 and I want to colour even rows differently from odd rows.

```
    <div *ngIf="AreThereMyOldMessages">
      <div *ngFor="let oldm of MyOldMessages;let i of MyOldMessages.length">
        <tr>
          <td>{{i}}<br>
            {{oldm.text}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="AreThereMyNewMessages">
      <div *ngFor="let message of MyNewMessages;let i of MyNewMessages.length">
        <tr>
          <td>{{i}}<br>
            {{message.text}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </div>
    </div>
  </table>
```

I want to colour each rows alternatively but this code prints all the rows in same colour. I have set a CSS file which colours each row accordingly using

```
table tr:nth-child(odd) td
```

this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tr:nth-child(odd)` will match table row elements that are an odd child. In your markup, each `tr` is indeed an odd child (first) of its parent `div`.

You would either need to change the markup or apply the css style to its parent `div`.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <ng-container *ngIf="AreThereMyOldMessages">
      <tr *ngFor="let oldm of MyOldMessages;let i of MyOldMessages.length">
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="AreThereMyNewMessages">
      <tr *ngFor="let message of MyNewMessages;let i of MyNewMessages.length">
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this make sense

Answer (score 0):

Try the following CSS:

```
table tr:nth-child(even){
          background-color:red;
          }

table tr:nth-child(odd){
          background-color:black;
          }
```

Comment: That prints everything in black

Comment: could you create a template?

Comment: I am sorry I don't know what that is :|